# Replicate H Lookup Functionality in Python Pandas for Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, if-statement

Question - How to best attempt the problem as nested loops is slowing the process and not giving the desired result

Same thing can be done in the Excel using Hlookup, but as it is a repetitive exercise, I need to automate it

I have the below lookup table.

```
lookup = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': ['Apple','Mango','Guava'],'Rate':[20,30,25],
               'Desc':['Apple rate is higher', 'Mango rate is higher', 'Guava rate is higher']})
```

My objective is to mark desc in my input data wherever the rate is greater than as mentioned in lookpup table

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Apple':[24,27,30,15,18], 'Mango':[28,32,35,12,26],
                       'Guava':[20,23,34,56,23]})
```

Expected Output data sample -

```
output_data = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'Apple':[24,27,30,15,18], 'Mango':[28,32,35,12,26],
                       'Guava':[20,23,34,56,23], 'Desc':['Apple rate is higher', 
                                                         'Apple rate is higher, Mango rate is higher',
                                                         'Apple rate is higher, Mango rate is higher, Guava rate is higher',
                                                         'Guava rate is higher', '']})
```

I have tried using the loop and created two list which gives me the index and value to be inserted. I am confused how to progress to next step and it seems a very slow method as I have multiple nested loops

```
for i in range(0,len(lookup)):
var1 = lookup['Fruit'][i]
value1 = lookup['Rate'][i]
desc1 = lookup['Desc'][i]

for j in range(0, len(input_data.columns)):
    var2 = input_data.columns[j]
    a=[]
    b=[]

    if var1 == var2:
        for k in range(0, len(input_data)):
            if input_data[var2][k] > value1:
                a.append(desc1)
                b.append(k)
        print (a)
        print (b)
```

Output of my code

['Apple rate is higher', 'Apple rate is higher', 'Apple rate is higher']
[0, 1, 2]

['Mango rate is higher', 'Mango rate is higher']
[1, 2]

['Guava rate is higher', 'Guava rate is higher']
[2, 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How you do what you asked for

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def desc_fruit_column(rate, desc, series):
    high_rate_mask = rate < series
    out = np.empty(series.shape, dtype=object)
    out[high_rate_mask] = desc + ", "
    out[~high_rate_mask] = ''
    return out

desc_columns = [desc_fruit_column(rate, desc, input_data[col]) 
                for rate,desc,col in zip(lookup.Rate, lookup.Desc, lookup.Fruit)]
input_data['desc'] = np.sum(desc_columns, axis=0)
input_data['desc'] = input_data['desc'].str.rstrip(", ")
```

Since this is pretty dense code I will try to explain a bit. For each column
`rate < series`
gives you a true/false list being true whenever the fruit value is over the rate. Then `out[high_rate_mask] = desc + ", "` gives you the relevant text for every true and `out[~high_rate_mask] = ''` puts an empty string in the position of a false.  The `np.sum` sums the columns i.e. puts together the strings and finally the `.str.rstrip(", ")` removes the `", "` in the end.

And you get

```
   Id  Apple  Mango  Guava                                               desc
0   1     24     28     20                               Apple rate is higher
1   2     27     32     23         Apple rate is higher, Mango rate is higher
2   3     30     35     34  Apple rate is higher, Mango rate is higher, Gu...
3   4     15     12     56                               Guava rate is higher
4   5     18     26     23
```

### What you should have asked instead

I am a visual person and prefer the relevant columns to be colored instead of having some extra text.

You could do that like this

```
input_data.style.highlight_between(left=[np.nan,*lookup.Rate], axis=1, color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: the one-liner answer you have provided is not easily readable nor is it good `pandas` practice since you use explicit `for` loops

Comment: @gold_cy you're right it was a bit dense and needed more explanation. You're not right about the for loop though. Using for loops with a small, fixed number of iterations is fine. If you were looking to optimize the code for run time you would leave the for loop alone and try to replace the `.apply`. But premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep in mind the feedbacks for the question. The solution is working perfectly

Comment: @gold_cy actually I changed my mind. You're right it was pretty hard to read. I rewrote it now. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using a combination of `pd.merge`, `melt`, and `groupby`.

```
tmp = pd.merge(
    input_data.melt(ignore_index=False) \
              .reset_index(), 
    lookup, 
    how="inner", 
    left_on="variable", 
    right_on="Fruit"
)

vals = tmp.loc[tmp["value"] > tmp["Rate"]] \
          .groupby("index") \
          .agg({"Desc": ", ".join})

pd.merge(input_data, vals, right_index=True, left_index=True, how="left")

   Id  Apple  Mango  Guava                                               Desc
0   1     24     28     20                               Apple rate is higher
1   2     27     32     23         Apple rate is higher, Mango rate is higher
2   3     30     35     34  Apple rate is higher, Mango rate is higher, Gu...
3   4     15     12     56                               Guava rate is higher
4   5     18     26     23                                                NaN
```

`tmp` is a join between the `lookup` and `input_data` in order to have them in one DataFrame so we can compare the values quickly between columns and keep the `Desc` attached to the relevant rows. `vals` ends up being the rows where the condition you describe is met and then we `groupby` the `index` that we kept from the original `input_data` table and concatenate the values for the `Desc` column. Lastly the output joins the `input_data` on the `vals` using the original `index` from the `input_data` as the join condition. We make sure to use a `left` join to keep the original rows if the condition is not met.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly.